App Store Connect API error while reading App information of BundleID
Trying to get App related to the bundle ID using App Store API:
https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/bundleIds/{id}/app

I'm receiving error 404:
"errors" : [ {
    "id" : "ec7b1469-fe54-4ad5-9f2b-f665c31a6358",
    "status" : "404",
    "code" : "PATH_ERROR_REALTIONSHIP",
    "title" : "The URL path is not valid",
    "detail" : "The relationship 'app' does not exist on resource 'bundleIds'"
  } ]

Tried to pass both Bundle ID id and Bundle ID itself as {id}. Error is the same. The app exists in the store.

@ShehataGamal, I want to get the valid response from the API.

The funny moment is that the error code is mistyped - "realtionship" :)

is the app available in US?

@user16930239, I don't know how it's relevant. Yes, the app is available in US.

Based in the error detail:

"The relationship 'app' does not exist on resource 'bundleIds'"

Looks like you are fetching relationship "bundleIds/app" which might not be present, can you re-confirm if you are passing the {id} part correctly for you bundle-id?

@Iprakshv, I pass bundle id id there, but I also tried to pass bundle id itself.

For {id}/profiles the API works as expected.

From documentation you can use GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/bundleIds/{id} where id is your bundle ID
So delete the /app path literally the 404 response is telling you to delete the URL path
If response is 200 the you will have a BundleIdResponse.data.relationship.app
The app object is BundleId.Relationships.App.Data

You didn't read the documentation carefully. The link that was quoted in the questions shows the valid endpoint: GET https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/bundleIds/{id}/app

Nice Hint. Still have you tried if the response object contains your app?

Yes, I tried, the response object only contains bundleIdCapabilities and profiles. Thanks for cooperation, I downvoted your answer since I don't remember how bounty works.

Just a trivial question have you already registered your bundle ID ?

@jacori, as mentioned in the question, the app is in the App Store, thus we, smart humans, can infer that it's bundle ID is registered.
